# Why is heading (h1-6) a separate category (tag) in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to wrap my head around why headings (h1-6) are a concept of their own in HTML/CSS separate from any regular style. It appears to me there is no good reason as it just confuses the user by adding to the available tag universe whereas all that it does can be accomplished by being just another regular style defined as, for example:

```
.headStyle1
{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

and then, instead of using a separate tag `<h1></h1>`, you just do something like:

`<span class="headStyle1">My Heading</span>`

And you live happier because you have one tag less to have to be dealing with in your working memory, heading are just another style rather than its own category.  To me, simplicity is a virtue.

Please explain if I am wrong and if there is a reasonable justification for this addition in complexity.

Comment: You can just not use them, you can not use any tags bar div tags if you really want. It is easier to type `<h1></h1>` for all your heading text rather than `<div class="heading1"></div>`.

Comment: @steo, it is indeed a question coming from a critical evaluation and scrutiny angle.  see the last sentence in the post:  `Please explain if I am wrong and if there is a reasonable justification for this addition in complexity.`

Comment: @gaynorvader, that is true, however, the CSS would look cleaner, simpler, with fewer levels of hierarchy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure h1-h6 have been in the spec long before any modern formatting options came about, probably even before CSS.  My understanding is their significance is two-fold: auto formatting your text into a header and search engines.  Because of the latter they are probably still in the spec as opposed to many other depreciated tags.  Also, HTML's spec hasn't always made perfect sense historically.

Comment: +1 @RandomUs1r.  that sounds convincing

Comment: Again, I'd argue that `h1{*/code*/}` is neater than `.heading1{*/code*/}` Also, people often have trouble with nested classes such as the difference between `#header.heading1` and `#header .heading1` in css. At the end of the day, I feel that if you really don't want to use it, don't and it being there has no real negative effect on anyone.

Comment: There is no such thing as “a separate style category in HTML/CSS”. Asking for “justification” for something that does not even exist sounds like trolling, but in any case it is non-constructive and asks for a debate rather than solutions to a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think about the reason that html semantic markup was created in the first place. Take a look at the W3C spec...

> A heading element briefly describes the topic of the section it
>   introduces. Heading information may be used by user agents, for
>   example, to construct a table of contents for a document
>   automatically.
>
> There are six levels of headings in HTML with H1 as the most important
>   and H6 as the least. Visual browsers usually render more important
>   headings in larger fonts than less important ones.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-H6

HTML is not just a framework for stylesheets, it is a way to "mark up" information. The span tag has very little meaning to screen readers or to search engines, however, the h1 tag means quite a bit.

Why stop at heading tags? We could just put everything in a span tag, get rid of `p`, `em`, `cite` and nearly every other tag and use styles to indicate importance. Then everyone who looked at the site would know what was important and what was less important. The problem would start when someone using a screen reader was accessing the site, or a search engine. By using semantic markup, you make the internet 'better'. You allow search engines now and in the future understand what is on the website you are creating.

Best to use the markup that exists. It is a way to define the type of content that is on the page. It really is simple once you embrace the 'complexity'.

Comment: i am convinced now.  thanks.

Comment: particularly i like the search engine rationale

Comment: do not discount the ADA (american disabilities act) accessibility reasoning either. some clients (especially those who get funding from the government... such as schools and universities) are required to be ada accessibile. it is not uncommon for an institution to be entangled in a lawsuit if their code is not up to snuff. while this may have little to do with the heading tags, it has a lot to do with well formed semantic markup.

Answer (score 4):

It's a semantic tag, designed to designate the importance of a particular heading with regard, and contrast to, the *other* headings on the page; for example an `h1` is the *most* important heading, whereas `h2` is slightly less-important.

It describes, and is not designed to describe, any presentational aspect of the content, merely the importance/significance relative to the other headings, which denotes similar importance the content that follows that heading (sort of).

References:

- [Heading elements, at the Mozilla Developer Netork](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements).
- [Heading elements, from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-H6).

Comment: well, i would argue that other styles are more often than not also fit into some hierarchy of importance relative to one another, yet they don't impose a whole new tag just because of that.

Comment: Seriously? What other tags denote any implicit/explicit importance of their content?

Comment: not tags, user-defined **styles** in most CSSs.

Comment: But a particular style denotes no particular importance to its content, except that, perhaps, inferred by the human reader. The use of specific tags is to impart a *semantic* information in a manner that can be logically parsed and understood, regardless of its consumer.

Comment: well since google kills all kind of styles there are only the tags left and then he starts to judge by the tags using h tags and giving their text some higher ranking than the other text on the page. it is just semantics that got a bit of a styling from the old days when css wasn't there yet

Comment: Like David said, it is to emphasize importance.  An example where this is used is in a textbook.  Title of Book - Level 1, Unit title - Level 2, Chapter Title - Level 3, etc.

It is also important for SEO, where text inside a heading tag is considered more important, and produces better results.

Answer (score 2):

The heading tags provide semantic meaning to a document, providing structure to a document without styling.

For example, they help make website accessible to those using screen readers. A screen reader wouldn't understand the importance of headStyle1 compared with h1.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use them, because they mean a lot for searching bots like Google, etc. Here's an example: You write an article and name it `Current situation in our company`. Now, if I were to find your article by any chance and forget to save an URL, I might not ever be able to Google it, because Google would rate it as some part of text on your website instead of ***important heading***.