# Why are h1-h6 different tag names in HTML?

Tags: html, history

Why are `h1` through `h6` different tags in HTML, rather than having a syntax like `<heading level="1">`? I'd be interested to know the history behind the decision (and the same for the different lists, `ol` and `ul` rather than a common list).

So far, my research hasn't turned anything up. The [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-H6) actually groups them all as "Headings", describing them jointly. Someone asked a similar question on Stack Overflow [once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553545/why-is-heading-h1-6-a-separate-category-tag-in-html-css), but that discussion was about the value of semantics and not the reasoning for this particular language design choice.

**EDIT:** I'm not asking about the SEO implications of one or the other, I'm looking specifically for answers around why the creators of HTML chose the syntax they did.

**EDIT 2:** This question can elicit a lot of opinion but there exists a factual answer, and it was found by Jukka in the comments below: http://infomesh.net/html/history/early/. I assumed the opinion part of this discussion was had when HTML was first created, and was looking for that rather than trying to rehash that debate.

Comment: The question is about historical background, so I don’t think it is primarily opinion-based. It might be regarded as too theoretical for SO, though, since the answer would presumably have no practical impact on HTML authoring or any kind of programming.

Comment: The `h1` through `h6` tags were taken from SGMLguid, see http://infomesh.net/html/history/early/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why are h1 through h6 different tags in HTML, rather than having a syntax like `<heading level="1">`?

[Because that's how they were originally defined in 1993](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt):

> ```
> Headings
>
>    Six levels  of heading are supported. (Note that a hypertext node
>    within a hypertext work tends to need less levels of  heading than
>    a work whose only structure is given by the nesting of headings.)
>
>    A heading element implies all the font changes, paragraph breaks
>    before and after, and white space (for example) necessary to render
>    the heading. Further character emphasis or paragraph marks are not
>    required in HTML.
>
>    H1 is the highest level of heading, and is recommended for the
>    start of a hypertext node.   It is suggested that the the text of
>    the first heading be suitable for a reader who is already browsing
>    in related information, in contrast to the title tag which should
>    identify the node in a wider context.
>
>    The heading elements are
>
>                 <H1>, <H2>, <H3>, <H4>, <H5>, <H6>
> ```

You must also realize that there was minimal attribute usage in the original HTML spec. Each element served a specific purpose toward marking up documents with an emphasis on being easy to write and easy to read. I can only assume that a tag along the lines of `<heading>` would have been flat-out rejected because it would be too long to type, and would get in the way of the content of the page.

The usage predates any concept of external stylesheets, so selectors could not have played any role in the decision for the naming convention.

Once the elements were defined, there was no reason to rename them as it would cause backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: I won't suggest the edit myself since it may be too minor, but if you put `<!-- language: lang-none -->` in your post just before your code block it will [tell the syntax highlighter](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to do no highlighting.

Comment: Actually, TimBL describes them "... as defined in the CERN SGML guide. Their definition is completely historical, deriving from the AAP tag set." in this [document from 1992](http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html)

Comment: @Alohci, that's really good info. Feel free to update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first explanation I can find is that it gives you a default set of tags that can be customized readily with CSS. Otherwise you would need to customize different levels of headers with a `class` attribute in addition to the  `level` attribute that you mentioned.

This way there's one tag that contains the default CSS attributes, and you only need to mention the header by its tag in order to customize it.

**EDIT**
I also realized that the post you linked to had another good reason: dedicated header tags make SEO a ton easier. I would imagine it would be easier for search engines to look for the existence of certain tags than to interpret the attribute.

Sub-Edit: If SEO matters to W3C at all (and I'm sure it does, otherwise we probably wouldn't have as much support for `meta` tags), then they would probably not intentionally make changes that make the function of Search Engines less efficient. So if they care about SEO, I would expect it to have an impact on their decision on syntax.

Comment: That's not true though, since in CSS you can match on arbitrary attributes. So styling a level 1 header would be `heading[level="1"]`. While it's slightly more verbose, the style all headings scenario is much shorter: `heading` rather than `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6`

Comment: @ehdv, `heading[level="1"]` has a higher specificity than the single element selector, but more importantly, `h1-h6` elements existed *before* CSS.

Comment: If you can match CSS straight to a tag, it's much cleaner and faster than matching a tag _and_ an attribute.

Comment: Good point about the elements being before CSS. However, I would suppose that if W3C really wanted to, they could have specified the existence of a `header` element with `level` attributes. That's a pretty weak argument though.

Comment: Didn't header tags exist before search engines, too?

Comment: @ehdv That syntax is very new (CSS2). The first Internet Explorer that supports that syntax is 8, released in 2006, more than 10 years after the tags were introduced.